# Relacionar tablas en Power BI para gráfico de casetas(peajes) Logística

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, powerbi, relaciones

Paso a comentar en que necesito ayuda. Cargue dos tablas del mismo excel a mi Power BI.

1-En la primer tabla tengo una base de casetas tomadas por nuestros vehículos. Trae las columnas de "Concesionaria-Fecha-Hora-TAG-Entrada-Salida-Importe". En la primer pagina del BI cree un grafico en donde veo la cantidad de "importe" de cada TAG. La base tiene información de 2años de casetas.
2-En la segunda tabla tengo la relación lineal de "TAG(es un numero adicional que marca el numero de TAG, ejemplo si es el 1ro, 2do, etc.)-Serial(es el numero de TAG como tal, como viene en la calcomanía ejemplo OHML0xxxx etc.)-Unidad(vehículo al que pertenece el TAG)-Sucursal-Operador.

Bien, lo que quiere hacer es conseguir lo siguiente, de la primer tabla sacar el importe que gastaron todos los TAGS(seriales) pero relacionar los números de TAGS con la otra tabla que tiene a que chofer esta asignado. Para poder visualizar el gasto total de TAGS, pero antes de ver los TAGS como tal, ver el nombre del chofer asignado a dicho TAG.
Con eso mismo podría después jugar en visualizar por sucursal, por unidad(vehículo), realice varias prueba pero no logre dar con la relación como tal. Cree una relación entre las tablas, pero creo que no funciono. Algún consejo para que pueda avanzar? gracias.

Actualización: Ya pude realizar la relación de las tablas con las columnas "TAG", pero ahora tengo un nuevo error como si no tuvieran relación las tablas. Algún dato de porque pasa esto?. Lo que quise hacer es que en la columna "Operador" aparecieran los nombres de los operadores que tiene asignado cada TAG que estan en la otra tabla "Lista de TAGS".

[image: Prueba numero 129310293]